# How can I create RGB composite from a set of rasters

Tags: qgis

I have a lot of 4 bands rasters with bands: blue-green-red-NIR, and I need to create 3 bands rasters with bands: red-green-blue. How I can automizate this process using QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Use gdal_translate from the command line https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html as

`gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 3 -b 2 -b 1 input_4band.tif output_RGB.tif` 
possibly with advanced parameters supported by the GeoTIFF driver https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html.

Comment: File "<input>", line 1
    gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 3 -b 2 -b 1 f:\temp\LC08_L1TP_171021_20180526.tif f:\temp\rgb\LC08_L1TP_171021_20180526.tif
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: How did you launch gdal_translate? You should run it from the Windows command window of Linux shell. You seem to use Windows, how did you install QGIS? If you have used OSGeo4W installer open the "OSGeo4W Shell" and run the command from there.

Comment: Oh! thanks great! I'm a novice in it. How can I run it for  all my files in one step?

Comment: That's not really a GIS thing, but something like `for %1 in (*.tif) do (gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 3 -b 2 -b 1 %1 RGB_%1)` should work.

Comment: I tried gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 3 -b 2 -b 1 f:\temp\%.tif f:\temp\rgb\%.tif and it doesn't work

Comment: Certainly not but did you try with my "for ... do" example? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192039/how-to-do-a-for-loop-in-windows-command-line for more examples.